# Laravel 5.5 @include only displaying plain text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm new to laravel and i'm trying to use @include for my header and footer but only displays plain text.

```
@inlcude('includes.header')
```

@inlcude('includes.footer')

[Here are both the files location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvrCk.jpg)

Here is my web.php file:

```
 <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

[All i get is just plain text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKAvM.jpg)

Comment: It's @include. It's typo

Comment: You spelled @include wrong

Comment: Thanks, i feel stupid for using copy paste...

Comment: @Kyle If you didn't, finding reason for issue would take longer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, change `@inlcude` to `@include`